# Fire custom event Vanilla JS, detect on Vue instances.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im currently integrating multiple Vue instances on my website, can't make the entire website a Vue instance and use components as there is a conflict possibility and other issues.

So for example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vueOne"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vitae sem eget tortor accumsan pellentesque ac commodo quam. Fusce efficitur, nisl non vehicula venenatis, libero augue efficitur nisi, non mollis nulla enim nec dolor. Curabitur leo diam, aliquam ac nisl in, cursus eleifend elit. Praesent euismod dapibus nisi ac semper. Donec massa lectus, vestibulum ut tristique eget, mollis eu nunc. Morbi dignissim lacinia pharetra. Maecenas consectetur libero sed risus cursus mattis</p>
    <div id="vueTwo"></div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#vueOne',
            data: {
                count: 0
            }
        });
        new Vue({
            el: '#vueTwo',
            data: {
                count: 0
            }
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can fire a custom event in Vanilla JS and have the Vue instances detect this?

Comment: what's your objective? please explain more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the same logic.. i create a vue instance for messaging only. This way i can call events from non-vue and use them in vue and backwards..

```
window.Event = new class {
  constructor() {
    this.vue = new Vue();
  }
  fire(event, data = null) {
    this.vue.$emit(event, data);
  }
  listen(event, callback) {
    this.vue.$on(event, callback);
  }
}
```

In a component i have a event listener:

```
created () {
    Event.listen('notification', function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }
```

and i can send a message like this:

```
Event.fire('notification', {
    title: 'Hello from notification throug message :)';
});
```

because the event class is created on the window, it is accessable from every component, and every function. This is a easy way for communicating between vue instances, vue -> vanilla and vanilla -> vue.

And because it is a vue instance for messages only, the load is very little. You can add as many event listeners as you want.. you can send all kind of messages to different listeners, or create multiple listeners for the same message.

Comment: is this applicable on vue 3?

Answer (score 6):

The events setup on your vue elements/components are/use the same type of event listeners setup on regular elements. So you can get a reference to the element you have set the event listener on, and call dispatchEvent with your custom event.

For instance if you had an event called `my-event` setup on one of your divs like

```
<div id="vueOne" v-on:my-event="myListener">{{count}}</div>
```

You could use [`querySelector("#vueOne")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a reference to that element, and then call [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) on it

```
document.querySelector("#vueOne").dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent("my-event") );
```

---

Demo

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vueOne',
  data: {
    count: 0
  },
  methods:{
    myListener:function(){
      this.count++;
      console.log("listener called");
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#vueTwo',
  data: {
    count: 0
  }
});

setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector("#vueOne").dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent("my-event") );
},2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vueOne" v-on:my-event="myListener">{{count}}</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vitae sem eget tortor accumsan pellentesque ac commodo quam. Fusce efficitur, nisl non vehicula venenatis, libero augue efficitur nisi, non mollis nulla enim nec dolor. Curabitur leo diam, aliquam
  ac nisl in, cursus eleifend elit. Praesent euismod dapibus nisi ac semper. Donec massa lectus, vestibulum ut tristique eget, mollis eu nunc. Morbi dignissim lacinia pharetra. Maecenas consectetur libero sed risus cursus mattis</p>
<div id="vueTwo"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up doing it and was surprised it worked so easy. In fact, I am paranoid as to whether it's too good to be true because everyone says to always use Vuex, and secondly all discussion is about `$emit` and not for these 'non-vue' scenarios, so it's always about child/parents, etc. But custom event seems to work just fine and normal `@my-event` attrs pick it up just great. For a small app, it should be ok, right?